# Map column to other values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following data:
[image]

I want to match the `Date` and `Value` col to the `Mapped Date` and `Value` colume:

I am doing this with:

`=COUNTIFS($A:$A;E2;$B:$B;F2)`

However that does not give me the Higher/Lower colume which I want to map. Basically it should look like the `expected results` col.

Any suggestions how to map this value?

I appreciate your answer!

PS.: One problem with just using:

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A;E8;$B:$B;F8);C8;"")`

the value in `row 20` gets marked with 0 because the if goes sequentially...

Comment: Are you familiar with `=VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: @Taosique Please provide an example, cause I do not get how to apply the `vlookup` function. How can this be realized with my `Countif` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of [@Peter Albert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247974/check-two-values-with-vlookup/22248100#22248100).

use this one in `G2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$19,MATCH(E2 & F2, $A$2:$A$19 & $B$2:$B$19, 0)),"")
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Is this also possible within the `COUNTIF` function?

Comment: no, I don't think so, Countif only can tell you whether this combitiation exist in columns A:B, but can't tell you where it is.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! My problem is that when pulling the formula down I get: `You cannot change part of an array`. I know that I can apply it to one row(the way you described it), but how to apply it to many more?

Comment: there're two options for you: **1)** write this formula in G2, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and than drag it down. **2)** select `G2:G23`, _with selected range_ enter formula in formula bar `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$19,MATCH(E2:E23 & F2:F23,$A$2:$A$19 & $B$2:$B$19,0)),"")` and than press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Wow! I have to say simoco you are the best! Thx for your help and also learned a lot alonf the way! +1